# ReadableStream.pipeTo() function does not exist in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to download large files (500mb - 2gb) using StreamSaver it works fine on Chrome but
as you can see here

```
ReadableStream {locked: false}
locked: false
__proto__: ReadableStream
cancel: ƒ cancel()
constructor: ƒ ReadableStream()
getReader: ƒ getReader()
locked: (...)
pipeThrough: ƒ pipeThrough()
pipeTo: ƒ pipeTo()
tee: ƒ tee()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "ReadableStream"
get locked: ƒ locked()
__proto__: Object
```

but on Firefox:-

```
    ReadableStream
    locked: false
    <prototype>: object
    cancel: function cancel()
    constructor: function ReadableStream() ​​
    getReader: function getReader() ​​
    locked:   ​​
    tee: function tee() ​​
    <get locked()>: function locked()
  <prototype>: Object { … }
```

as you can notice there is no pipeTo function that exists on firefox.
This is my download event function

```
 function down (event){
        console.log(event.data.stream());
        
        const stream = event.data.stream();

        const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(fileNameRef.current);
      if( stream.pipeTo){
        stream.pipeTo(fileStream);
      }
        const peer = peerRef.current;
        peer.write(JSON.stringify({ wait:true}));
    }
```

Is there any way I can make it cross-browser support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ReadableStream#pipeTo()` and `ReadableStream#pipeThrough()` are not supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#Browser_compatibility) (yet), because they require support for [`WriteableStream`s, which Firefox does not yet support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream). Some [polyfills are availble](https://github.com/MattiasBuelens/web-streams-polyfill).

Comment: Actually it's not so much that pipes require WriteableStreams, FF already has the code for WriteableStreams but are waiting to have support for pipes before releasing both.